# Are RPi peripherals from version 1 compatible with RPi B?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, piface

I have some original Raspberry Pi devices that I want to use with the RPi B version. Are old Raspberry Pi Shields compatible with the new Raspberry pi?

Specifically, I have an Xtrinsic MEMS Sensor Evaluation kit and a PiFace Digital 2.

I cannot seem to find a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first 26 pins are the same between the old and new boards. So physically they should work. There are a few caveats to that however:

1. most 26 pin headers will not clear the extra pins on the newer B+ and Pi2.
2. The method used to enable I2C, spi and other kernel modules has changed.
3. the software (drivers etc.) may not work with the newer OS images.

You can overcome the first by getting some stacking headers, and the second by doing a little research. The third may be a harder challenge to overcome. I would suggest you email the manufactures or check their websites for more detailed info.

It seems someone over at [Newark](http://www.newark.com/piface/piface-digital-2/io-expansion-board-raspberry-pi/dp/78X5847?mckv=spZZ8SG4V_dc%7Cpcrid%7C61403636915%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7Cpiface%20digital%202%7Cmatch%7Cp&CMP=KNC-GUSA-SKU-MDC?gross_price=) has already asked this question for the PiFace

> Yes, PIFACE DIGITAL 2 is compatible with Raspberry Pi model B+.

Things don't look as promising for the MEMS Sensor Kit. According to [Element14](http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/mems-sensor-board/blog/2014/01/30/using-the-xtrinsic-sensor-board-for-raspberry-pi) while the hardware does not seem to be a problem, it appears the software (driver poses some problems). Though the posts that mention a problem are from September 2014. This [page](http://www.element14.com/community/thread/41811/l/using-mems-sensors-evaluation-board-on-rasberry-b?displayFullThread=true) (last comment) hints that there maybe some hope

Comment: And 4. The location of the header has shifted a little between the 26 and the 40 pin header so if you have a Hat/Shield it might not sit squarely above the Pi anymore [(See picture here)](https://cdn.volumio.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RaspberryPib+comparison.jpg)